# Localize VirtualKey.Control (WinRT)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I would like to localize the VirtualKey for Control.
Currently there is code like this:

```
using Windows.System;
var message = "Press " + VirtualKey.Control.ToString() + " + D for deletion!";
```

Is there an API which can be used to have the following?

- Press Control + D for deletion! (on an English system)
- Press Steuerung + D for deletion! (on a German system)

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to hard-code words like "press" and "deletion" and hope it will get localized.  Nor does it make any sense to use VirtualKey.Control, it is always the Ctrl key anywhere in the world, even though the key caption might read differently.  Try to post a more realistic example, one that won't just trivially be localizable by translating the *entire* string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As VirtualKey is an enumeration, you cannot translate a member of an enumeration directly, but you can use it as the key for resource files, building up a localization system:

I followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) tutorial to build up a simple localization system on a Windows 8.1 Application; these are the steps I followed (summed-up)

1. Create a folder called "Strings"
2. Inside the folder, create a folder for the default language you want to support and name it accordigly (see a full list of possible codes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/supported-languages))
3. Create a Resources.resw file in that folder
4. Add the strings you want to add - *If you want to support the use of `VirtualKey.xxx.ToString()`, I strongly suggest you to use the same identifiers of the enumeration; for instance: if you want to translate the control character, call the new resource "Control"* -  (this is what I did):[image: How I did]
5. Copy and paste that folder for a number of times equal to the number of languages you want to support (I did it twice):
   [image: Folders]
6. Edit the Resource.resx file accordingly to the language you're translating to.
7. In code, refer to each translated string with

   ```
   var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
   loader.GetString(VirtualKey.xxx.ToString());
   ```

   That's what I did on a TextBlock in MainPage.xaml:

   ```
   var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
           this.txbCtrl.Text = String.Format("Press {0}-Z to undo", loader.GetString(VirtualKey.Control.ToString()));
   ```

And that's the result for the language it-IT:
[image]

To test it for other languages, I followed the tutorial, even if I don't like it:

1. Open the Control Panel and go to Clock, Language, and Region > Language
2. Note that the language that was displayed when the app was ran is the top language listed that is, on my system, Italian.
3. To test the app with another language, select the language in the list and click Move up until it is at the top. Then run the app.

*NB: If you do not have all three of these languages on your machine, add the missing ones by clicking Add a language and adding them to the list.*

In my case I have italian listed for first and English (UK) as the second one, but if I swap them:
[image: Mylangs]

and run again the application, this is the result
[image: Result]

and if I add de-DE:
[image]

with these resource files:
en-GB:
[image: en-GB]

and it-IT:
[image: it-IT]

and de-DE:
[image: de-DE]

*Notice that I've called the English Control key "Control" and the Italian one "Ctrl"; it works perfectly*

I Hope this helped.

If you have more questions, just ask!

LuxGiammi

EDIT: this is a solution, even though I recognize this is not a good one (anyway, it's the best I could think of). Anyway, as stated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/42d03ceb-a7b6-44c4-9988-406b681fe676/ctrl-key-in-localized-windows-systems?forum=clr) for WinForm applications, it is not necessary to do it because evrybody would understand you if you use the defualt names for the keys (i.e., the one in the enumeration, just like you're doing now).

EDIT2: this solution, however, sets everything up for a future "full" localization for your application. This way half of the effort is made at the beginning of the developemnt process.